# Will Jar Jar Binks be a character in any of the new Star Wars Films?

Tags: character, star-wars, the-force-awakens

Has it been confirmed or (please god) denied that Jar Jar Binks will appear in the new *Star Wars* films?

Comment: Related question on SFF.se: [Could Jar Jar Binks live long enough to appear in the next Star Wars trilogy?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/55325/3567)

Comment: Related but i am asking if it has been confirmed or not

Comment: Well, while filmmakers shouldn't be influenced too much by fan-fuss, they surely aren't completely dumb or living on Mars. ;-)

Comment: I doubt it. Star Wars chronologically ended with the great addition of the Ewoks. I hope THEY will be the protagonists in the new Star Wars movies. Wicket forever!

Comment: If it's been confirmed you would have heard about it, mainly through the cries of a million fan boys shaking their fists in anger, cursing Abrams, saying their redeemer has turned out to be nothing more than a wolf in sheep's clothing.

Comment: Andy Serkis stated that he is [*not* playing Jar Jar Binks](http://moviepilot.com/posts/2014/07/16/star-wars-episode-7-andy-serkis-talks-those-jar-jar-rumors-2073371?lt_source=external,manual) or any similar role.

Comment: Now it's 2021 and it's ironic they managed to screw up the sequels even without Jar Jar.

Answer (score 9):

**I think it’s unlikely he will appear… as a character, that is.**

In [an interview with *Vanity Fair*](http://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2015/05/star-wars-the-force-awakens-vanity-fair-cover), JJ Abrams mused the possibility of a return for Jar Jar:

> But here is something I can disclose, which I suspect fans—a majority of them, anyway—will find most heartening of all: at one point during the effects review, while watching a sequence with spaceships flying low over a desert planet, Abrams asked to pause the scene. With a light pen, he drew a little squiggle on a sand dune.
>
> **“I have a thought about putting Jar Jar Binks’s bones in the desert there,”** he said.
>
> Everyone laughed.
>
> Abrams laughed, too, but insisted, “I’m serious!” He pointed out that the shot zips by in a second, if that. “Only three people will notice,” he said, “but they’ll love it.”

Given that Abrams clearly understands the general ill-feeling towards Jar Jar, and was willing to suggest this to a journalist, I think he’s unlikely to do an about-face and bring him back as a character in the film.

Of course, that doesn’t preclude him appearing further down the road, after Abrams has left the franchise, but it becomes steadily more unlikely. I don’t think it will happen.

---

**Update, 8 December 2015:** at a [Star Wars press event](http://www.ew.com/article/2015/12/06/live-blog-star-wars-force-awakens-press-conference), Lucasfilm president Kathleen Kennedy confirmed that Jar-Jar is not appearing:

> Kaling says she knows Kennedy can’t talk about what’s in the movie, so she asks what’s not in the movie. “Jar Jar is not in the movie,” Kennedy says, to hoots from the audience.

Answer (score 3):

Whilst I have not read any article concerning Episode VII featuring any mention of Jar Jar Binks he definitely is alive at the time the Emperor and Darth Vader are killed but well I'm not sure how long Gunguns live he would probably be pretty old if he is still alive though considering the mass hatred the character received I doubt JJ Abrams would consider including him in the film if he did it would be a subtle reference probably background reference but as Jar Jar has no meeting with Luke Skywalker and he is going to be in the film I see no reason for Jar Jar to appear.

His [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jar_Jar_Binks) entry for the Galactic Civil War era simply says,

> **Galactic Empire**
> After the formation of the New Order, Binks was considered an ally of
> the new Emperor, and an Imperial HoloVision report shortly after the
> end of the Clone Wars mentioned that he had personally sent Senator
> Binks to an undisclosed location.
> He was succeeded in his post as Representative of Naboo in 6
> BBY by Pooja Naberrie, by appointment from Queen
> Kylantha.
>
> **The end of the Civil War**
> Binks was alive and well in 6.5 ABY, and was present on Coruscant
> during its liberation from the Galactic Empire by troops of the New
> Republic. While he was never involved in this liberation, he was
> situated relatively close to some of the action.

The only thing you can do is wait and see if he appears at all in the movie but considering he has nothing to do with the original trilogy whose principle characters are supposed to play a vital role in creating the New Republic Jar Jar a known associate of Palpatine (whether he agreed with him or not) is unlikely to involve himself in anything to do with any new characters linked with the principle characters but we'll see.

Comment: Update: Chuck Wendig in his novel Aftermath: Empire's End which was written to bridge the gap between Return of the Jedi and the Disney fan fiction sequel trilogy explains that Jar Jar ends up as a street clown entertaining children on Naboo. I personally don't care for these novels or the Disney sequels, I would suggest reading the Heir to the Empire Thrawn trilogy if you want to read a true sequel to ROTJ but thought it was something worth adding if you're interested in what the Disney timeline considers Jar Jar's fate to be.

Answer (score 0):

Big ol' spoiler below:

> Jar Jar Binks is **not** in The Force Awakens.